# Double Clicking Batch File Windows cannot find file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I've found variants of this question being asked all over the place, and I've attempted all of the actual answer I've found out there (including changing the registry for associations). The basic issue is this:

1. I create a batch file (simple batch that has an echo and a pause) on the desktop or in any folder in the computer.
2. I double click the batch file to run it and get:

[image]

Workarounds include:

1. Right click and run as administrator
2. Open command prompt and call the batch file by name

I was dealing with the issue by just using those workarounds for a while, but I'm starting to think my inability to get certain programs to work properly (android.bat in Android Studio won't run because of file not found despite being there, for instance) is related to this issue. If I can't get it fixed in the next week, I'm likely going to reformat.

Additional info:

1. This is Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
2. There are no other file types which have this double-click execution issue
3. If I call a batch file from another batch file using the workarounds, it works
4. This happens regardless of the folder I'm in, and does not happen on a Hyper-V virtual machine using the same copy of windows
5. All windows updates are run and I've done virus scans and such - the only other thing that's been going wrong simultaneously is that the machine seems to be slowing down a bit (in particular when I try to open file dialogs in ANY program - which now take ~5 seconds to open instead of being instantaneous).

Any ideas would be much appreciated! It may just be time for a reformat (it's been a year or so).

Edit: Wasn't aware of SuperUser. Seems like this question may be more appropriate over there!

Edit 2: Anyone over here have an ideas?

Comment: Try fixing .BAT-related registry entries via the [File Association Fixer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/file-association-fixer-2-windows-10-8-7), reboot and see if it works.

Comment: Just tried it and rebooted, no effect at all.

Comment: Have you run `sfc /scannow` already? If you create a new user do batch files work? If not what are your user and system PATH variables set to?

Comment: Just finished running, "Verification 100% complete. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Answer (score 6):

Check your system environment COMSPEC. It should be something look like %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe. If it was altered for what ever reason , bat files won't be able to run by double click.

Comment: My problem solved following this guideline!

Answer (score 1):

You are running the Batch File in a "privileged space".  Microsoft has become wise to this fact, and you need to address this accordingly.

Most viruses and malware exploit the root of the OS Drive.

What you need to do is to create a folder and move your batch file in there.

C:\test\test.bat

As an aside, in the "server world" it is actually considered to be a poor practice to install/run your application on the same drive as the OS.  Consumer laptops/desktops is fine, but in the server space, this is a bad practice.  For example, if your web server or database was to run an errant process, and the log space was to fill the drive, it can quite literally kill the OS.

Just my couple bits for thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I mentioned, it doesn't matter what folder I put it in. I did that to avoid including my username information in the path. The typical path is C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\test.bat . I would never put something in C: except for demo purposes.

Comment: Are your users set to be Power Users or better?  Do you need to apply CACLS/XCACLS on the folder/file to apply appropriate permissions?  And, what is in the content of the bat file?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I just echo and pause. The file runs if I use a non-admin command prompt. Double-clicking is the time it doesn't run.

Comment: I would look at your ePO, and/or virus Settings/Policies.  Your Sys Admin may have put restrictions against running batch files.  You have to think in those terms.

Comment: Well this is a personal computer so I am my sys admin. I'll check that though, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/virii "The plural virii, though common, is based on a misunderstanding of Latin. There is no example of a plural for the word virus in Latin."  <-- Not even for biological viruses. So do correct that.

Comment: @barlop - done.

Comment: You are totally wrong in what you say, you made up the term "privileged space", that sounds like something out of a social sciences SJW class, and contrary to your claims, a program over there has no extra rights than any other program, for example, c:\aaa.bat cannot write a file c:\bbb.txt, (unless aaa.bat is run administrative, but then any program run administrative can write there).

Comment: Also a log file is not going to kill an operating system. In theory it might crash it if the server doesn't place a limit on the size of its logs. but don't call a crash a "kill", that's absurd.  There is actually a command "kill" for terminating a process. To refer to a crash as a kill is a wild exaggeration.

Comment: You write "if your web server or database was to run an errant process, and the log space was to fill the drive"  <-- And suppose the log or any data produced by the application, goes to a different partition/drive? Would you still say one shouldn't install an application on the same drive/partition as the OS. If so you may need another reason

Answer (score -1):

I copied the "cmd.exe" file from another PC and pasted it into the windows/system32/ folder. That fixed my problem.

Comment: I don't see how this would make a difference.  However, to give you the benefit of the doubt, I am not voting to delete this answer.  But the answer requires a reason.  Did you get the idea from somewhere, did they post a reason ?